# Adding new row and positioning pagination for that row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I am making a dynamic table. I have a working add button which adds rows to the table, I also have a working pagination. Now I wont to combine this two.

When I add a new row I wont to be placed at the last page of pagination where the row is created. For now I always stay at the first page of pagination and manually go to last page.

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

script.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

var table = angular.module('myTable', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ngStorage']); 


table.controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        "todos":[
            { "id":1,"text":"drive a car"},
            { "id":2,"text":"go to work"}
        ]           
    });
    $scope.todoData = $localStorage.todos;  
});


$scope.addRow = function (arr) {
            console.log(arr);
            arr.push({'id':$scope.id, 'text': $scope.text});        
            };
});
```

index.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="addRow($storage.todos)">New record</button>

<table>
    <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr dir-paginate="todo in todoData">
                <td>
                    {{ todo.id }}
                </td>
                <td>                
                    {{ todo.text }}
               </td>
           </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>

<dir-pagination-controls
    max-size="5"
    direction-links="true"
    boundary-links="true" >
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

add `current-page="myCurrentPage"` to the tag you have `dir-paginate` in, in your example the `<tr>` tag. Add `$scope.myCurrentPage = Math.ceil($scope.todos.length/$scope.entryLimit);` to your addDeveloperRow function.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/btiGc9fusLJqY1ioP8Hw?p=preview)

Comment: please provide more information than "something missing" so we can address the issue

Comment: When I implement your code nothing new happens I still stay at the first page. Maybe I should add or change something in the ng-click directive also. What you wrote makes perfect sense.

Comment: If you can provide a functional jsfiddle/plunker of your code that I can work with, I could solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sina Gh!

Comment: Sina Gh can you join me in chat room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99116/pagination